# Efficiently defining many nginx custom error pages

Tags: nginx, custom-errors

I created some custom 4xx and 5xx HTML error pages for most errors listed on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). I'd like to install them on any nginx server I set up, without impacting performance too much.

Following the documentation I came up with this configuration directive for an error:

```
error_page 404 /nginx/404.html;
location = /nginx/404.html {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/errors/404.html;
        internal;
}
```

I put this in `/etc/nginx/snippets/errors.conf` and can include the snippet in all my `server` blocks.

**This works great, however...**

It prepends nearly 50 `location` directives to every `server` block on the box.

Is this excessive, and is there a more performance-friendly way to achieve the same thing? I avoided server-side includes, if statements, and rewrites thinking it would require more server resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't map each error page to it's own location you can do with a single location directive:

```
error_page 402 /error/402.html;
error_page 403 /error/403.html;
error_page 404 /error/404.html; 
... etc. 

location = /error/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/errors/;
}
```

Comment: So obvious now, so elusive a few hours ago :) Thank you

Comment: I had to remove `=` from the location line as its no longer an exact match

Answer (score 0):

Why not try Server Side Includes (`ssi on;`) in your error location? Then, you could define a single error page for all error codes. It's dynamic without involving a real programming language. Here's a good example of a template that illustrates most of what you can do with the technology: https://www.cambus.net/nginx-and-server-side-includes/